# Proof by Contradiction to Prove Theorem that is not True

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Based on the following incorrect **Theorem**, why is this proof by contradiction not valid?

**Theorem**
**If** $x+y=10$
**Then**  $x\neq 3 \text{  and  } y\neq 8$

**Proof**
*Assume:*
$x+y=10$
$x=3$ or $y=8$

*Let* $x=3$ and $y=8$
*Since* $x+y=3+8=11\neq 10$ we have a contradiction based on the assumptions.

Based on this haven't we just proven the above theorem which we know to be incorrect. The steps I have been taught for proving something using proof by contradiction is to *assume* $P\land \lnot Q$ which I believe that I have done correctly. Then you simply want to *derive* something that is not true, which I also feel that I have done ($x+y\neq 10$).

So, my question is, where have I gone wrong/what is it that I am not understanding correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have set up things correctly: Assume $x+y=10$, and then, to start the proof by Contradiction, you (correctly) assumed that it is not true that $x \neq 3$ and $y \neq 8$. And the latter means that $x=3$ *or* $y=8$. But from that, you cannot infer that $x=3$ *and* $y=8$, which is what you need in order to get to $x+y=11$ and thus to your contradiction.

Comment: I cannot see why that is the case. It seems to me that the truth value for $x=3\lor y=8$ would be true when both $x=3$ and $ y=8$?

Comment: @JacFrall True, from $x=3 \land y=8$ you can indeed infer $x=3 \lor y=8$. But in order for your proof to work, you need to go the other way around: Your Proof by Contradiction goes like this: $\neg (x \neq 3 \land y \neq 8) \Rightarrow (x =3 \lor y=8) \Rightarrow x = 3 \land y=8 \Rightarrow x+y=11$.

Comment: Look at your proof. You assume $x=3$ or $y=8$ ... and yet on the very next line you say 'Let $x=3$ and $y=8$' ... wait!  Where does that come from? Certainly not from your assumption, because from $x=3$ or $y=8$ you cannot infer $x=3$ and $y=8$.  And so is this a *new* assumption? A second assumption?  But then when that second assumption runs into a contradiction, all you u have shown is that it cannot be trrue that $x=3$ and $y=8$ ... the first assumption does not get discharged, and hence you have not shown that it cannot be true that $x=3$ or $y=8$

Comment: Yes that makes much more sense now. Thank you for helping me see that it is a stronger statement and thus you cannot assume more than the initial $P\land \lnot Q$

Comment: @JacFrall Cool, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

this theorem is wrong

$P: \bigg[x+y=10\implies (x\ne 3\land y\ne 8)\bigg]\iff \bigg[(x=3 \lor y=8)\implies x+y\ne 10\bigg]$

Suppose $x=3$, you take $y:=7$ so $x+y=10$ contradiction so your theorem is wrong

**by contradiction :**

$\lnot P :\quad x+y=10 \land (x= 3\lor y= 8)$

$x+y=10$ and $x=3$ we take  $y:=7$, so the proposition $\lnot P$ is right.

---

I remind you $P:(s\implies t)\iff (\lnot s\lor t)$ so $\lnot P :s\land \lnot t$
To avoid any confusion you have to add quantifier so the proposition becomes

$ P :\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{N}^2,\bigg[x+y=10\implies (x\ne 3\land y\ne 8)\bigg]$

So the negative is :

$\lnot P : \exists (x,y)\in \mathbb{N}^2,\quad (x+y=10) \land (x= 3\lor y= 8)$

We only need to find one 2-tuple that satisfies the proposition, so $(x,y)=(3,7)$ fits. We conclude $\lnot P$ is right thus $P$ is wrong

Comment: Yes, I understand that the Theorem is not True. This is why I was confused. I was showing that some obviously false theorem was true using proof by contradiction, asking for clarification.

Comment: I added a proof by contradiction

Comment: I see. What confused me was I thought you could let $x=3 $ and $y=8$ in the proof by contradiction since this seems to satisfy the $x=3 \lor y=8$ part of $\lnot P$.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: $\forall \cdots  P$ and $\exists\cdots \lnot P$

Comment: $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{N},\; P$ and $\exists x,y\in \mathbb{N},\;  \lnot P$

Comment: When assuming $P\land \lnot Q$ the $\lnot Q$ part is $x\neq 3\lor x\neq 8$. I could not understand, while assuming $\lnot Q$ you could not let $x=3$ and $y=8$. The reason I thought you could do this was because the statement $x\neq 3\lor x\neq 8$ is still true when you let $x=3$ and $y=8$. It turns out that you cannot use both based on $\lnot Q$. Since I was assuming $P\land \lnot Q$ and getting a statement that is False ($10\neq 11$), I felt that the proof was complete, using proof by contradiction. Therefore the theorem is True. But we know it can't be, that's why I was confused originally.

Comment: $Q$ is $x\ne 3\land y\ne 8$ so $\lnot(P\implies Q)\iff P\land \lnot Q$ with $$\lnot Q :x=3\lor y= 8$$